# Notification on Ether Received

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Can any one help me to find the solution, if I received a Ether in my wallet, I should be able to send 1% back to the Payee automatically?

Thanks
Amit M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be achieved from a 'normal' wallet address. Instead you will need to write and deploy a smart contract.

[Here](https://www.ethereum.org/token) is an example of a smart contract written in [Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/).

Have a read through, and have a play. Distic has detailed a basic example which will achieve what you want.

You can get some [free Ether](https://ethtools.com/ropsten/tools/faucet/) on the Ropsten test network to practice and verify that your code works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Thomas , I am planning to automate my wallet cash backs.

Comment: Can I use FallBack Method in that Case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that directly,
but you can deploy a smart contract with the following instructions:

`function () public payable {
  msg.sender.send(msg.value*0.01);
  myAddress.send(msg.value*0.99);
}`

where myAddress is your address.
Then you will have to ask the payee to send his ether 
to your contract's address.

Comment: Well, a smart contract is automatic.
Once deployed you give its address instead of yours,
and you receive the payments in your pocket.

Comment: Can I use FallBack Method in that Case?